# Enable multiple inputs by checking a checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, input

I'm getting bad with an issue with javascrpt and inputs in a form...
I have a form composed by multiple groups composed by a checkbox and two select list, i need to activate the select lists of the group when their checkbox is checked... how can i do??? here's my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="room1" class="bookcheckbox1"><b>Select Room</b>
Adults<select class="bookselect1">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
Children<select class="bookselect1">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" value="room2" class="bookcheckbox2"><b>Select Room</b>
Adults<select class="bookselect2">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
Children<select class="bookselect2">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function able(obj,x){
        if(obj.checked ==true)
            {
                document.getElementById("x"+x).disabled=false;
                document.getElementById("y"+x).disabled=false;
            }
        else
            {
                document.getElementById("x"+x).disabled=true;
                document.getElementById("y"+x).disabled=true;
            }
    }
 </script>
<input type="checkbox" value="room1" class="bookcheckbox1" onchange="able(this,1)"><b>Select Room</b>
Adults<select class="bookselect1" disabled="true" id="x1">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
Children<select class="bookselect1" disabled="true" id="y1">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" value="room2" class="bookcheckbox2" onchange="able(this,2)"><b>Select Room</b>
Adults<select class="bookselect2" disabled="true" id="x2">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
Children<select class="bookselect2" disabled="true" id="y2">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
</body>
```